# What is the difference between :: and . in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am confused by the difference between `::` and `.`. They look the same except that their syntax are different.

> ```
> let mut guess = String::new();
>
> io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
>     .expect("Failed to read line");
> ```

["Programming a Guessing Game" from *The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html)

In the above case, I access the function `new()` in `String`. What is the difference between `String::new()` and `String.new()`? Is `.` only for methods?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`.` is used when you have a value on the left-hand-side.  `::` is used when you have a type or module.

Or: `.` is for value member access, `::` is for namespace member access.

Comment: Can I assume that with `String::new()`, all I am doing is accessing a member of that namespace. In the case of `io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)`, `stdin()` is a member of `io`, but the returned value isn't part of any `namespace`, and is just an instance (doc is saying `pub struct Stdin`)? So it's a struct? Which is like an object?

Comment: String is a struct, new is a static method (no self as first argument), so you access it by `::`. io is a namespace where you access the inner "things" (structs, traits, ...) with `::`.

Comment: @Dan: I'm not sure what you're asking.  `String::new()` is calling a function that is defined by the `String` type.  It's no different to calling any other function.  `io::stdin()` returns a value, so `.read_line` looks up and calls the method `read_line` defined by the `Stdin` type.  The only way in which this is different to calling a "bare" function is that the thing on the left hand side of the `.` (the `Stdin`) is passed as the `self` argument to `read_line`.  And "object" is so *hideously* overloaded that I can't really answer that.  It depends on what you mean by "object".

Comment: This might be the root of my confusion. What makes something a type or a module? For `pub fn stdin() -> Stdin`, the doc states that a `new handle` is constructed, with `Stdin` being `Struct std::io::Stdin`. They don't seem to be called a type or a module.

Comment: @Dan: That's a bit like asking "what makes something a struct or a function?"; they are what they are because they're defined that way.  I don't know what else to tell you.  I get the feeling that there's something fundamental here you don't understand, but I'm not sure what it is.  In the case of `stdin`, it doesn't specify whether the result is a type or module because it *must* be a type, because you can't return a module.  Modules are purely for organising things.

Comment: Coming from C# to Rust and this works almost like instance members and static members, `.` means calling an instance member of a type and `::` is like accessing a static member for a type. The instance methods for a type in Rust look similar to an extension method in C# `public static void Foo(this MyType myType)` against `fn foo(&self)` in Rust. Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but I think this analogy could help C# developers like myself that are trying Rust for the first time.

Answer (score 20):

A useful distinction I found useful between `::` and `.` is shown in [Method Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch05-03-method-syntax.html).

When calling an instance of a `fn` in a `struct`, `.` is used:

```
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

impl Rectangle {
    fn area(&self) -> u32 {
        self.width * self.height
    }
}

fn main() {
    let rect1 = Rectangle {
        width: 30,
        height: 50,
    };

    println!(
        "The area of the rectangle is {} square pixels.",
        rect1.area()
    );
}
```

Associated functions on the other hand, are functions that do not take `self` as a param. They do not have an instance of the `struct`:

```
impl Rectangle {
    // Associated Function
    fn square(size: u32) -> Rectangle {
        Rectangle {
            width: size,
            height: size,
        }
    }
}
```

`::` is used instead to call these functions.

```
fn main() {
    let sq = Rectangle::square(3);
}
```

Whereas `.` is used to return a method (a function of an instance of a struct).

Comment: cool, explanation, just to summarise `::` is used for static methods, namespace variables. While `.` is used of members(instance)

Answer (score 0):

I like to think if the method takes `&self` as a parameter, we use `.` syntax and if it does not, then we use `::` syntax.

For example, to quote @Dan's answer, to calculate the area, we need an object, it's `length` and it's `height`. So we pass `&self` as a parameter and we use `.` syntax. To create a new square, we don't need an existing object and we use `::` syntax.

`x.do()` means execute the function `do()` on the object `x` and `x::do()` means execute the function `do()` from the namespace of `x`.

In rigorous words, `.` is used for methods of a struct and `::` is used for associative functions of a struct.

Comment: While this is true, this doesn't explain all cases for using `::`. It is also used for accessing module members. The accepted answer explains this well.